# meaning of "biblical in its silliness"

Tags: meaning

["In its entirety" is an established idiom](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/in%20its%2Ftheir%20entirety) and has a pattern `in its + noun form of an adjective`.

It seems that the pattern is a commonly used pattern, e.g. "in its silliness".

[From a comment](https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/left_behind_2014)

> Left Behind is biblical in its silliness.

However, googling "in its silliness" and "biblical in its silliness" gets nothing definition or explanation of it.

I guess the reviewer is somehow making a complaint upon that movie but I don't understand the exact meaning of it. Can someone help me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Biblical" in this general context is jocular slang lazy critic-ese for "extreme".

Comment: Thank you. How about "in its silliness"? Does it just mean "the movie is silly", "not good at many kinds of aspect"?

Comment: Everything has an amount of silliness. Some things are more silly than others. "It is (xyz) in its silliness" is idiomatic for "its amount of silliness is (xyz)"

Comment: Thank you. Does "xyz" here is some kind of measurement, like passion, intensity or plot; or just a value of a specific measurement, like the amount of water is **2 liters**?

Comment: If you want to try to ascertain a value level on a pretentious and facetious construction, go ahead, but the usage is non-standard. You don't say "The bucket was 2 litres in its fullness", it just wouldn't happen, you'd just say "The bucket was 2 litres full" if you even wanted to word it like that.

Comment: Thank you. Could I paraphrase "amount of silliness" to "extent of silliness" and measure it in {tiny silliness, silliness, very extent}?

Comment: @RobertH Ugh. It gets uglier and uglier, this construction. The original sentence stands alone; it is pretentious and facetious, as I say, but it is idiomatic and exploits a cliche. I wouldn't even bother to think about paraphrasing it, as whatever you want to do with it makes it worse. I've given you an answer which can be considered to be a band-aid of an answer, no good comes of continuing to pick the scab. Wait till someone else has a go at answering it.

Comment: Thanks for your patience. Sorry for bothering you so much. The last question, could I paraphrase the original sentence to "this movie is probably the worst I've ever watched"?

Comment: @RobertH You could, but it wouldn't express the fact that the reason you think it's so bad is because you see it as silly.